# ASP.NET MVC Ajax Jquery to update checked boxes in an Html Table and submit changes. Checked check-boxes are false when submitted to controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to update an html table and then submit it's changes to a controller using ajax and jquery. Currently I'm able to populate and make changes to the table however when I submit it to the controller no changes have been made. The checkbox in the collection is always false even though changes have been made from the UI.  I've been trying a number of approaches so the code may be a bit messy.

Create.cshtml below:

```
@model POS.BusinessLayer.Models.userRoleURF

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>View</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>userRoleFeature</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userRoleFeature.urfCompanyId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.companyDropDown.CompanyId, Model.companyDropDown.data, "--Select Company--", new { @class = "form-control", id = "CompanyId" })
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.urfCompanyId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userRoleFeature.urfCompanyId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.userRoleFeature.urfRoleId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.userRoleDropDown.RoleId, Model.userRoleDropDown.data, "--Select Role--", new { @class = "form-control", id = "RoleId" })
                @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.urfRoleId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.userRoleFeature.urfRoleId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div id="loadingRoles" style="display: none;">
                    <img src="~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
                </div>


            </div>
        </div>




        <table class="table" id="featureTable">
            <tr>


                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.urfResults.First().userFtrDescription)
                </th>



                <th>
                    @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.urfResults.First().urfEnabled)
                </th>


            </tr>

                @*foreach (var item in Model.urfResults)*@
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.urfResults.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr id="featureRow">

                        <td>

                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.urfResults[i].userFtrDescription)
                            @*@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.urfResults[i].userFtrDescription)*@
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="checkbox">
                                @Html.CheckBoxFor(x => x.urfResults[i].urfEnabled)
                                @*@Html.EditorFor(modelItem => modelItem.urfResults[i].urfEnabled)*@
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                }

        </table>
        <div id="loadingFeatures" style="display: none;">
            <img src="~/Content/Images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
        </div>



        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input id="mysubmitbutton" type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>


@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/userRoleFeatureIndex.js")
```

JavaScript Code below:

```
$(function () {



    $("#mysubmitbutton").submit(function(){
        var tblFeature = $("#featureTable");
        // If selected roleID is not null
        var CompanyID = parseInt($("#CompanyId").val());
        var RoleID = parseInt($("#RoleId").val());

        var array = [];
        $('#featureTable > tbody  > tr').each(function (elem) {
            var item = {};
            item.userFtrDescription = $(this).find("td > #urfResult_" + elem + "_userFtrDescription").val();
            item.urfEnabled = $(this).find("td > #urfResult_" + elem + "_urfEnabled").val();
            array.push(item);
        });
        var data = JSON.stringify(array);


        $.ajax({
            url: "/userRoleFeature/CreateURF/",
            type: "POST",
            data: { selectedCompanyId: CompanyID, selectedRoleId: RoleID, featureList: tblFeature},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });


    $("#CompanyId").change(function () {
        // this will call when Country Dropdown select change

        var CompanyID = parseInt($("#CompanyId").val());
        if (!isNaN(CompanyID)) {


            var ddRole = $("#RoleId");

            ddRole.empty(); // this line is for clear all items from role dropdown
            ddRole.append($("<option></option").val("").html("Select Role"));




            // Here I will call Controller Action via Jquery to load role for selected company
            $("#loadingRoles").show();
            $.ajax({
                url: "/userRoleFeature/roleList",
                //url: "@Url.Action('roleList','userRoleFeature')",
                type: "POST",
            data: { selectedCompanyId: CompanyID },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (roles) {
                $("#loadingRoles").hide();
                $.each(roles, function (i, roles) {
                    //ddRole.append($("<option></option>").val(val.Value).html(val.Text));
                    ddRole.append("<option value='" + roles.Value + "'>" + roles.Text + "</option>");
                });
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                $("#loadingRoles").hide();
                alert(request.responseText);;
            }
        }); // End of Ajax Call





    }  // End if Company Id is selected
    }); //End Company Change Function


//start if roleId changes
$("#RoleId").change(function () {

    // If selected roleID is not null
    var CompanyID = parseInt($("#CompanyId").val());
    var RoleID = parseInt($("#RoleId").val());

    if (!isNaN(RoleID)) {


        var tblFeature = $("#featureTable");
        //$("#featureTable tbody tr").remove();
        tblFeature.find("tr:gt(0)").remove();


        // Here I will call Controller Action via Jquery to load features for selected role
        $("#loadingFeatures").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/userRoleFeature/urfList",
            //url: "@Url.Action('urfList','userRoleFeature')",
            type: "POST",
            data: { selectedCompanyId: CompanyID, selectedRoleId: RoleID },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (urfResults) {
            $("#loadingFeatures").hide();
            var trHTML = "";

            $.each(urfResults, function (i, item) {
                //ddRole.append($("<option></option>").val(val.Value).html(val.Text));
                trHTML += "<tr>";
                //trHTML += "<td>" + item.userFtrDescription + "</td>";
                //trHTML += '<td><input id= "urfResult_' + i + ' _userFtrDescription" name= "urfResults[' + i + ' ].userFtrDescription" type="Text" value="' + item.userFtrDescription + '" style="border:none; width:100%" /></td>'
                //trHTML += "<td><input id= 'urfResult_" + i + "_userFtrDescription' name= 'urfResults[" + i + "].userFtrDescription' type='Text' readonly value='" + item.userFtrDescription + "' style='border:none; width:100%' /><input name= 'urfResults[" + i + "].userFtrDescription' type='hidden' value= '" + item.userFtrDescription + "' /></td>";
                //trHTML += "<td><input name= urfResults['" + i + "'].urfEnabled type='checkbox' value='" + item.urfEnabled + "'/> <input name= urfResults['" + i + "'].urfEnabled type='checkbox' value='" + item.urfEnabled + "'/></td>";
                //trHTML += "</tr>";


                trHTML += "<td><input id= 'urfResult_" + i + "_userFtrDescription' name= 'urfResults[" + i + "].userFtrDescription' type='Text' readonly value='" + item.userFtrDescription + "' style='border:none; width:100%' /></td>";
                trHTML += "<td><input id='urfResult_" + i + "_urfEnabled'  name= urfResults['" + i + "'].urfEnabled type='checkbox' value='" + item.urfEnabled + "'/> </td>";
                trHTML += "</tr>";




            });

            tblFeature.append(trHTML);





        },




        error: function (request, status, error) {
            $("#loadingRoles").hide();
            alert(request.responseText);
        }
    }); // End of Ajax Call






} // End if selected role is not null

}); //If roleId changes

});
```

Controller Code Below:

```
    [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(userRoleURF collection)
        {
            try
            {
                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                var blURF = new blUserRoleFeature();
                var myURF = collection.urfResults;
                var myCompany = collection.companyDropDown.CompanyId;
                var myRole = collection.userRoleDropDown.RoleId;


                foreach(var item in myURF)
                {
                    var iURF = new userRoleFeature()
                    {
                        urfCompanyId = myCompany,
                        urfEnabled = item.urfEnabled,
                        urfRoleId = myRole,
                        urfId = 0,
                        urfCreatedBy = 0,
                        urfCreatedOn = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1978"),
                        urfModifiedBy = 0,
                        urfModifiedOn = Convert.ToDateTime("01/01/1978")


                    };

                    //var result = blURF.urfCreate(iURF);

                }


                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {

                Response.Write(ex.Message);
                return View();
            }
        }



Model details below:
  public class userRoleURF
    {
        public userRoleDropDown userRoleDropDown { get; set; }
        public IList<userRoleFeatureG>  urfResults { get; set; }
        public userRoleFeature userRoleFeature { get; set; }
        public companyDropDown companyDropDown { get; set; }


    }



   public class userRoleFeatureG
    {

        //public int userFtrId { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Feature Description")]
        public string userFtrDescription { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Enabled")]
        public bool urfEnabled { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: After clicking submit button it goes to the controller ? did you check with breakpoint?

Comment: What are you trying to do with all this? If your wanting to post back to your model, then just use `data: $('form').serialize(),` and remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",`

Comment: I checked the breakpoint I'm seeing in the collection the list values for URFResults however I'm not seeing where any of the checkboxes have changed they are all saying false.  I'm trying to submit through the form (id mysubmitbutton) and avoid using the java script  $("#mysubmitbutton").submit(function() however either way the values in the table are not change non of the checkboxes are returning true.

Comment: The only issue I'm having is with the checkbox always being false. Did some research and realized that their has to be two inputs when dealing with checkboxes one has to be hidden something like this: 
trHTML += "<td><input id='urfResult_" + i + "__urfEnabled'  name= urfResults['" + i + "'].urfEnabled type='checkbox' value='true' /><input   name= urfResults['" + i + "'].urfEnabled type='hidden' value='false' /></td>";  but it's still not working for me.

Comment: I figured out a work-around: 
I remove the standard beginform and used the submit button on click event to call a Jquery function locates all the checked boxes and places them into an array. Then it calls a controller which takes all the checked boxes and actions them:
So now my code looks like this:

Comment: Jquery Code:
$.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/userRoleFeature/submitURF',
            data: { id: chkItems, selectedCompanyId: CompanyID, selectedRoleId: RoleID },
            //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) { 
                //$('#spanResults').text(data.join(','));
                window.location.href = '/Home/Index'; 
            },
            error: function(e) {
                alert(e.message);
            }
        });

Comment: My Controller Code:
    public JsonResult submitURF(List<string> id, int selectedCompanyId, int SelectedRoleId)
        {
            var blURF = new blUserRoleFeature();
            var deleteResult = blURF.urfDelete(SelectedRoleId);
            foreach (var item in id)
            {
                var iURF = new userRoleFeature()
                {
                    urfCompanyId = selectedCompanyId,
                    urfRoleId = SelectedRoleId,
                    urfEnabled = true,
urfFeatureId = Convert.ToInt16(item)
                };
var result = blURF.urfCreate(iURF);

Comment: Please note that the controller is a JsonResult and not an ActionReslut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a work-around: I remove the standard beginform and used the submit button on click event to call a Jquery function. It locates all the checked boxes and places them into an array. Then it calls a JsonResult controller which takes all the checked boxes and actions them:

**Updated Jquery Code:**

$(function () {

```
var chkItems = new Array();

$('#mysubmitbutton').click(function () {

    var CompanyID = parseInt($('#CompanyId').val());
    var RoleID = parseInt($('#RoleId').val());

    $('#featureTable tr').each(function () {
        var row = $(this);

        if (row.find('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {
            var id = row.find('[type="checkbox"]').attr("value");
            chkItems.push(id);
        }
    });

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/userRoleFeature/submitURF',
        data: { id: chkItems, selectedCompanyId: CompanyID, selectedRoleId: RoleID },
        //contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            //$('#spanResults').text(data.join(','));
            window.location.href = '/Home/Index'; 
        },
        error: function(e) {
            alert(e.message);
        }
    });

});






$("#CompanyId").change(function () {
    // this will call when Country Dropdown select change

    var CompanyID = parseInt($("#CompanyId").val());
    if (!isNaN(CompanyID)) {


        var ddRole = $("#RoleId");

        ddRole.empty(); // this line is for clear all items from role dropdown
        ddRole.append($("<option></option").val("").html("Select Role"));




        // Here I will call Controller Action via Jquery to load role for selected company
        $("#loadingRoles").show();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/userRoleFeature/roleList",
            //url: "@Url.Action('roleList','userRoleFeature')",
            type: "POST",
        data: { selectedCompanyId: CompanyID },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (roles) {
            $("#loadingRoles").hide();
            $.each(roles, function (i, roles) {
                //ddRole.append($("<option></option>").val(val.Value).html(val.Text));
                ddRole.append("<option value='" + roles.Value + "'>" + roles.Text + "</option>");
            });
        },
        error: function (request, status, error) {
            $("#loadingRoles").hide();
            alert(request.responseText);;
        }
    }); // End of Ajax Call





}  // End if Company Id is selected
}); //End Company Change Function
```

//start if roleId changes
$("#RoleId").change(function () {

```
// If selected roleID is not null
var CompanyID = parseInt($("#CompanyId").val());
var RoleID = parseInt($("#RoleId").val());

if (!isNaN(RoleID)) {


    var tblFeature = $("#featureTable");
    //$("#featureTable tbody tr").remove();
    tblFeature.find("tr:gt(0)").remove();


    // Here I will call Controller Action via Jquery to load features for selected role
    $("#loadingFeatures").show();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/userRoleFeature/urfList",
        //url: "@Url.Action('urfList','userRoleFeature')",
        type: "POST",
        data: { selectedCompanyId: CompanyID, selectedRoleId: RoleID },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (urfResults) {
        $("#loadingFeatures").hide();
        var trHTML = "";

        $.each(urfResults, function (i, item) {

            trHTML += "<tr>";
            trHTML += "<td><input id= 'urfResult_" + i + "__userFtrDescription' name= 'urfResults[" + i + "].userFtrDescription' type='Text'  value='" + item.userFtrDescription + "' style='border:none; width:100%' /></td>";
            if (item.urfEnabled == true)
            {
                trHTML += "<td><input class='check-box'  id='urfResult_" + i + "__urfEnabled'  name= urfResults[" + i + "].urfEnabled type='checkbox' checked='true' value='" + item.userFtrId + "' /><input   name= urfResults[" + i + "].urfEnabled type='hidden' value='false'  /></td>";
            } else {
                trHTML += "<td><input class='check-box'  id='urfResult_" + i + "__urfEnabled'  name= urfResults[" + i + "].urfEnabled type='checkbox' value='" + item.userFtrId + "' /><input   name= urfResults[" + i + "].urfEnabled type='hidden' value='false'  /></td>";
            }

            trHTML += "</tr>";
        });

        tblFeature.append(trHTML);





    },




    error: function (request, status, error) {
        $("#loadingRoles").hide();
        alert(request.responseText);
    }
}); // End of Ajax Call
```

} // End if selected role is not null

}); //If roleId changes

});

**Updated Controller Code:**

```
public JsonResult submitURF(List<string> id, int selectedCompanyId, int SelectedRoleId)
        {
            var blURF = new blUserRoleFeature();
            var deleteResult = blURF.urfDelete(SelectedRoleId);
            foreach (var item in id)
            {
                var iURF = new userRoleFeature()
                {
                    urfCompanyId = selectedCompanyId,
                    urfRoleId = SelectedRoleId,
                    urfEnabled = true,
                    urfFeatureId = Convert.ToInt16(item)
                };
                var result = blURF.urfCreate(iURF);
            }
            return Json(id);
        }e:
```